# Let $U_1, U_2$ be subspaces of the real vector space $V$. Prove that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U_1, U_2$ be subspaces of the real vector space $V$. Prove that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$

Is my proof valid?

1. Firstly proving $U_1 \cup U_2 \space \text{is a subspace} \implies U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$

$\begin{align*}U_1 \cup U_2 \space \text{is a subspace} & \implies \alpha u_1+\beta u_2 \in U_1 \cup U_2 \space\space\forall u_1 \in U_1, \forall u_2 \in U_2, \forall\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R} 
\\ & \implies \alpha_0 u_1+\beta_0 u_2 \in U_1 \space\text{or} \space \alpha_0 u_1+\beta_0 u_2 \in U_2 \space \text{for some $\alpha_0, \beta_0 \neq 0$}
\end{align*}$

$\text{WLOG assume}\space \alpha_0 u_1+\beta_0 u_2 \in U_1$

$\begin{align*}
& \alpha_0 u_1+\beta_0 u_2 &&\in U_1 \\
\implies & \alpha_0 u_1+\beta_0 u_2 + (-\alpha_0)u_1 &&\in U_1 \\
\implies & \beta_0 u_2 &&\in U_1 \\
\implies & \frac{1}{\beta_0}\cdot\beta_0 u_2 &&\in U_1 \\
\implies & u_2 &&\in U_1 \text{(All by the properties defined on a vector subspace.)}
\end{align*}$

Hence $U_2 \subset U_1 \space \text{and similarly} \space U_1 \subset U_2.$
$\text{Thus} \space U_1 \cup U_2 \space \text{is a subspace} \implies U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$

2. Secondly proving $ U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1 \implies U_1 \cup U_2 \space \text{is a subspace}$

$\text{WLOG assume $U_1 \subset U_2$}$

$\begin{align*}
\text{Hence} \\
&u_1 &&\in U_2 \space \forall u_1 \in U_1 \\
&\alpha u_1+\beta u_2 &&\in U_2 \space \forall u_2 \in U_2, \space \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R} \\
&\alpha u_1+\beta u_2 &&\in U_1 \cup U_2
\end{align*}$

Hence $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1 \implies U_1 \cup U_2 \space \text{is a subspace}$

Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: It would be clearer if you write your proofs in English. In your proof that $U_1\subset U_2$ or $U_2\subset U_1$ it is unclear what the $u_1$ and $u_2$ are on the second line. In the first line they are arbitrary elements of $U_1$ and $U_2$, now on the second line are they still arbitrary elements? Do the coefficients $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ depend on the $u_i$?

Comment: I see my mistake now. My assumption they're still arbitrary elements in the second line is wrong. Thanks, and I'd appreciate if you could clarify what exactly you found unclear about the way I wrote my proof. Whether it was the formatting that made it difficult, or whether I didn't define what I was doing properly, so I can work on these things in the future.

Comment: Symbols like $\implies$ and $\forall$ can be good short-hands when you are sketching out possible proofs on paper (because you know what you mea, but not good for presentation of a proof (unless you really are working in a formal logic, where the meaning is well-defined).  It is clear from the algebra in the first part that your are trying to show that if a linear combination of $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in U_2$ belongs to $U_1$ then $u_2 \in U_2$, but this isn't quite strong enough to give what you are looking for: I think you need to use contradiction as I did in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. This is most certainly a duplicate. 2. This is not a "please check my proof" site. If you have specific doubts about your argument, then you should point out exactly which steps you are unsure about and why you are unsure about them. Otherwise, the question is off-topic as being "too broad". You are essentially asking one question for each step in your argument, "Is this step right?" "Is this step right?" "Is this step right?" That's multiple questions in a single post. Voting to close.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could post a link to the duplicate you're most certain exists if you found one it so I could learn from the discussions there. I couldn't find one myself that had anything similar to my proof attempt and could help me understand if I was going wrong with it. I've noted your other point and I'll be careful to be specific about my doubts in the future. Cheers.

Comment: [Union of two vector subspaces not a subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71872/742); 99 votes; 7 answers with positive score, top answer has 124 votes, second answer, with 87 votes has a proof, as does the third top answer, with 30 votes, and the fourth, with 14 votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of the first part is far from clear (see the discussion in the comments) and there is a quicker way to do the second part:

1. Assume that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$ and asssume for a contradiction that $U_1 \not\subset U_2$ and $U_2 \not\subset U_1$. Then we can find $u_1 \in U_1 \setminus U_2$ and $u_2 \in U_2 \setminus U_1$. But then $u_1$ and $u_2$ are both members of $U_1 \cup U_2$ and hence $u_1 + u_2 \in U_1 \cup U_2$, since we are assuming $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$. But then we must have either $u_1 + u_2 \in U_1$ or $u_1 + u_2 \in U_2$. In the first case, we have $u_2 = (u_1 + u_2) - u_1 \in U_1$ contradicting our assumption that $u_2 \in U_2 \setminus U_1$. Similarly we get a contradiction if $u_1 + u_2 \in U_2$. So our assumptions cannot hold: if $U_1 \cup U_2$ is a subset, then either $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$.
2. WLOG, we can assume that $U_1 \subset U_2$, but then $U_1 \cup U_2 = U_2$, which is given to be a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your proof is incorrect. You cant assume that the sum is in $U_1$, if you were only talking about one object $u_1$ you could assume WLOG that it is in $U_1$, but you are speaking of lots of objects, it may be the case that some of them are in $U_1$ and some of them are in $U_2$. Try contradiction instead.

Assume for a contradiction that $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace while $U_1\not\subset U_2$ and $U_2\not\subset U_1$.

Choose any $x$ such that $x\in U_1$ while $x\not\in U_2$. Chose any $y$ such that $y\not\in U_1$ while $y\in U_2$. The assumption that $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace implies that $x+y\in U_1\cup U_2$, meaning that $x+y\in U_1$ or $x+y\in U_2$, which is clearly a contradiction.

As for the second part of the proof, assumign WLOG $U_1\subset U_2$ , this implies $U_1\cup U_2= U_2$

Comment: You don't have to do any algebra in the second part.

Comment: @Carlyle I'm curious about that. Did you delete your response as I cannot see it?

Comment: @Carlyle: I am not a fan of proof by contradiction when it can be avoided. Unfortunately  I don't think your proposed way of avoiding it works. (And as you have just deleted your answer, it looks like you have doubts too.)

Comment: @martinkleins yes I did delete it, unfortunately it was incorrect, as Rob points out

Comment: @RobArthan Yes the way in your response is certainly more concise. For some reason I didn't realise that. We were typing our responses at the same time.

Comment: @RobArthan yes I did have doubts, I am more confident now, but the proof is no longer more elegant than the proof by contradiction

Answer (score 1):

The proof seems more or less correct, but more importantly it is very difficult to read and follow, I won't attempt to edit it as that might get too messy, so I'll rewrite your proof here with some improvements and comments for you to learn from:

Let $U,V$ be subspaces of a vector space $X$, then assume that $V\cup U$ is a subspace of $X$, we want to conclude that either $V\subseteq U$ or $U\subseteq V$

> Note that the reader is being guided through the thought process, rather than just being confronted with a heap of symbols

To show that either $V\subset U$ or $U\subseteq V$, we start with an arbitrary $u \in U$ and an arbitrary $v\in V$

> This is somewhat nonstandard, but actually quite a nice way of doing it, by choosing an arbitrary element from both, we postpone the decision of which inclusion we're going to try and prove

Then from the definition of a subspace we have that

$$v+u \in V\cup U$$

> Notice that I got rid of the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s, afterall you also get rid of them, just through a much more complicated procedure

Then from the definition of union, either

$$v+u\in V \  \mbox{ or } \  v+u\in U$$

Assume *w.l.o.g* that

$$ v+u \in V$$

Then since $v\in V$, we also have that $-v\in V$, so we have that

$$(v+u)+(-v) = u\in V$$

So given an arbitrary pair of elements $u,v$ in $U$ and $V$ respectively, either $u\in V$ or $v\in U$. Now If $U\not\subseteq V$ then there is some $u_0 \in U$ such that $u_0 \notin V$, then pairing each $v\in V$ with $u_0$ we find that $V\subseteq U$, we could also conclude that

$$V\not\subseteq U\implies U\subseteq V$$

So the proof is complete.

The idea you had is actually quite elegant when cleaned up a bit, so well done. For the other direction of implication however, there is a significantly shorter proof, notice that

$$A\subseteq B \implies A\cup B = B$$

For arbitrary sets. I'll let you figure out the rest

Comment: The conclusion of this argument is that from an arbitrary pair $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ we can conclude $u\in V$ or $v\in U$. This does not imply that $U\subset V$...

Comment: @JoshuaTilley thank you, I believe it is correct now, but it is no longer a rewrite of the OP's proof

Comment: Thanks for patching up your proof. It is now a proof by contradiction. I suspect this result may not be provable intuitionistically (i.e., that it requires a proof by contradiction).

Comment: @RobArthan That would be quite interesting, so is the statement "$((\neg\alpha \implies \beta) \land (\neg\beta\implies \alpha))\iff \alpha\lor\beta$" not probable intuitionistically? Because if so, it seems plausible that one could prove that the vector space theorem implies the set-subset version of the above statement, which would confirm your suspicion

Comment: $((\lnot \alpha \Rightarrow \beta) \land (\lnot \beta \Rightarrow \alpha)) \Rightarrow \alpha \lor \beta$ is not provable intuitionistically. Taking $\beta = \lnot\alpha$ it implles $(\lnot\lnot \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha) \Rightarrow \alpha \lor \lnot \alpha$ which is not provable intuitionistically (see Andreas Blass's answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910240/equivalence-between-middle-excluded-law-and-double-negation-elimination-in-heyti).